# Optional NoReturn: TypeHint for a function which sometimes raises an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Python offers the [NoReturn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn) TypeHint for functions which *never* return a value. What is the best practice for a function which only sometimes doesn't return a value?

```
def handle_value(value: str) -> ???:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value
    else:
        _raise_helping_func(value)
```

This function always either returns a string or raises an exception (calls another func which raises). Maybe it's:

- `-> Optional[str]`
- `-> Union[str, NoReturn]`
- `-> str`

I'm leaning toward the last one. Just keep it simple and call it a day, I just wondered if there's something I hadn't heard of.

Comment: I wouldn't use `NoReturn` because, as the docs state, it is for "indicating that a function *never* returns" (emphasis added). Additionally, your function only accepts strings as inputs. So if any value which isn't a string is given, the "contract" of the type signature is already invalid (and it should be expected that your function throws an error or produces an incorrect result).

Comment: I should be clear, the shown function is unnecesarily simple. I'm working with classes with many values and conditions, and just didn't want to add that complexity into the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be better handled in docstring. Type hints **imo** are for the possible return cases. We don't exclude type hints on functions that raise errors for the same reason. If it returns a string unless there's an error condition, just say that it returns a string.

If you use something like [numpystyle docstrings](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#method-docstrings) there is an explicit "Returns" section where you can include that info. For example:

```py
def handle_value(value: str) -> str:
    """Handles a particular value

    Parameters
    ----------
    value : str
        The value to be handled

    Returns
    -------
    str
        Returns a string if value is a string instance, else passes data to _raise_helping_func()
    """
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value
    else:
        _raise_helping_func(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function can either:

- return a string
- raise an error

Then the correct return type annotation is `-> str`. That means, *if* you get a return value, it’s a string. There is no other case. The exception case is not covered by the return type annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also leaning towards `-> str`. From [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#exceptions):

> **Exceptions**
>
> No syntax for listing explicitly raised exceptions is proposed. Currently the only known use case for this feature is documentational, in which case the recommendation is to put this information in a docstring.